# What is this weird integral?

Tags: random-variables, lebesgue-integral, markov-chains

I just read in a book on stochastic optimization, this weird integral:
$$\int V(x,z')Q(z,\mathrm dz')$$
where $z$ is a random variable and specifically a markov chain, $Q$ is the so called "state transition function" (don't know exactly what it is yet). The book says this is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. But I thought I've seen Lebesgue integrals before, but they just have the standard form $\int \cdots\mathrm d\mu$ for a measure $\mu$.

I've never seen a "$\mathrm d\cdot$" **inside** a function in the integral. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ is another standard (but slightly rarer) notation for $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ or $\int f\,d\mu$, used mainly in probability theory.  See p.177  of V.I. Bogachev's *Measure Theory* for a usage making this meaning clear.  The notation is sometimes clearer in contexts where there are multiple measures and variables at hand.  (You might find this intuitive: since $\mu$ is a measure we know about  $\mu(A)$ for sets, and you can think of $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ as being like a Riemann sum, writing the space as a union of lots of little sets $[x,x+dx]$ or $dx$, each getting weight $\mu([x,x+dx])$ or $\mu(dx)$.)

Another freaky notation is $\mu(f)$ for $\int fd\mu$, emphasizing the role of a measure as a *functional*, mapping functions $f$ to numbers $\mu(f)$.

In your case, $V(x,z')$ is a function of two states (numbers or points or whatever) and $Q(z,\cdot)$ is a measure, presumably the conditional distribution of your process's next state $z'$ given the current state $z$.  And your integral is what you get when you integrate $V(x,z')$ over $z'$ with respect to this measure.